# How would I separate numbers and from a string and return the summation of them?

Tags: python, for-loop, integer

I am given a string which is `loop_str="a1B2c4D4e6f1g0h2I3"` and have to write a code that adds up all the digits contained in 'loop_str', and then print out the sum at the end. The sum is expected to be saved under a variable named 'total'. The code I have written above although is reaching the correct answer, I am struggling on having to define total and create a for loop for this specific task.

```
sum_digits = [int(x) for x in loop_str.split() if x.isdigit()]
total=sum_digits
print("List:", total, "=", sum(total))
```

Comment: `total = sum(sum_digits)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have edited your code a little and the result is what follows:

```py
loop_str="a1B2c4D4e6f1g0h2I3"
sum_digits = [int(x) for x in loop_str if x.isnumeric()]
total = sum(sum_digits)
print(total)
```

##### Output

```
23
```

Note that there is no need to change `.isdigit()` to `.isnumeric()`

Answer (score 0):

you can extract all integers numbers like this:

```py
import re

total = sum([ int(i) for i in re.findall('(\d+)', 'a1B2c4D4e6f1g0h2I364564')])
print(a)
```

output:

```
364584
```

you should use regex to extract the integers from text like the above then sum all of them in the list.

if you want just digits you can remove `+` from regex like this:

```
import re

total = sum([ int(i) for i in re.findall('(\d)', 'a1B2c4D4e6f1g0h2I364564')])
print(a)
```

output:

```
48
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `isdigit()` as in their original code?

Comment: my answer supports both

Comment: Why does "the right answer" require regex when the requirement is "to define total"? OP already managed to retrieve the digits, without the regex added complexity